# azure mobile service custom api script server side timeout

Tags: api, azure, mobile, service, timeout

Good day, I implemented `exports.get = function(request,response)` of a custom api on a mobile service of azure. 
I download 5 thousands records from the database and then i prepare the json for the output.
The problem is that the time of downloading of all records is too long, for that my script goes into timeout. 
I was thinking if there is a way to increase the timeout of the response.